# What does 'take on an identity' mean?

Tags: meaning

Does it mean 'show an identity?'

I looked up the phrase in a number of dictionaries, but I haven't found an appropriate definition.

> Give yourself permission to improvise, to mimic, to ***take on*** a
> long-hidden ***identity***.

Comment: "**take something ↔ on** to begin to have a particular quality or appearance"

Comment: It can mean that you assume someone else's identity, or show a facet of yourself which the world does not know about, or adopt a false *persona* which isn't really you, like an actor.

Comment: It's like "become"